# Integrating Ebizmarts Sage Pay Suite and Aheadworks Advanced Newsletter

Tags: extensions, newsletter

I'm trying to integrate Ebizmarts Sage Pay Suite CE and Aheadworks Advanced Newsletter (not the built in Magento newsletter).

We have both of these plugins on our Magento store. Users can subscribe to the newsletter either on registration or through their account page but when ticking the sign up box on the checkout page the user doesn't get added to the mailing list. After much trial and error and discussion with Aheadworks I think the error lies in the Ebzmarts section as disabling this extension allows customers to register for the newsletter at checkout.

Does any one have any experience integrating these plugins or any ideas about how to go about debugging this?

Comment: Is it possible that sagepay overrides the default checkout template?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about third party modules

Answer (score 2):

The two most common causes of something like this are

1. Both extensions rewrite or replace the same class files, and only one can win
2. Both extensions change a block's template, but only one wins

Outside of leaning on the vendors for support (which often results in mutual finger pointing and/or uncertain blaming of the customer's system)

Tools like the [developer helper extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/developer-helper-1724.html) or [n98-magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) can help you diagnose these problems, but you'll need a developer, or a willingness to learn web/php development to make them work.